# Types of chromatogram shapes

Tags: chromatography

I'm trying to generate a testing set of different chromatograms to check peak detection (whether peak boundaries are detected correctly) and smoothing algorithms. Currently I'm figuring out which features of chromatograms I should vary for my tests. Hopefully someone could help fill my blanks. So far I'm thinking of all combinations of all bullet points:

- Peak shapes: Gaussian, ...?
- Sharp & wide peaks
- Different levels of skewness
- Baseline drifts: any types? Should it also resemble Guassian peak?
- 2 peaks next to each other:

  - Peak resolution e.g. from .2 to 1. Allows to test valleys & round peaks.
  - Different peak heights. Together with different levels of resolution allows to test valleys, shoulders, rider peaks.
- Tailing and fronting: are there some known distributions that resemble them?

As for smoothing:

- High frequency noise: uniform distribution?

So far this is what I've got for each resolution that I choose: [chromatogram-shapes.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17l7kJh94VD2rU2AEIHj6bkPth5lNmDbA/view?usp=sharing). Want to add baseline drift next, but haven't decided which distribution(s) it should resemble.

Comment: What exactly is your background? What chromatograms are we talking about, an artificial test set for testing what exactly?

Comment: @Karl, I'm a software engineer, though I'm learning chemistry/analytical chemistry/DSP to create chromatogram processing software. This is going to be an artificially generated test set to check algorithms like ApexTrack or maybe we'll come up with a new one some day. Currently I'm interested mostly in MS & DAD detectors and the types of signal they generate.

Comment: I strongly recommend you find yourself a cooperation partner with a chemistry degree, who helps you to firstly define a scope for your project.  DAD and MS are detectors, one for HPLC usually, the other for gas chromatography. They work fundamentally differently.

Comment: @Karl I understand the principles of how they work and I understand when/why/how they are used (not as well as a professional chemist of course). Though *I'd love* to have a chemist to talk to from time to time :) But note that this question is _not about spectra_ - it's about _chromatograms_ - they don't differ as much between detectors - it's still chromatography (I'm not talking about TOF either) hence it's still a time vs. intensity plot. Though sure - they may have some features of their own (absolute intensities, noise profiles) and that's one of the things that I'd like to know better.

Comment: Well, you brought up the detectors. ;-) And the detector type is *certainly* a major issue for your question. They have different noise levels, kind of disturbances, and dynamic range, linearity, ... But you also need to choose a chomatography. HPLC, GC, SEC, .... And what kind of samples?

Comment: There are plenty of databases with chromatograms in them, especially for MS.  You could mine those datasets for chromatograms...one example of such a database is GNPS/MASSive.

Comment: @CurtF. wooooow, I've been looking for such database for a long time, many thanks! I probably won't be using real samples for peak-detection testing, it's more convenient to control exactly all the variables. But real samples will help me a lot too. If you know other places with MS (or other detectors) - I'd be very grateful if you pointed me there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good to know that someone is working in DSP *and* chromatography but there are many software out there like PeakFit, why a new one?

0. Your first test could be peak detection as function of resolution as well their height ratios. Find out under what thresholds your peak detection fails. This is the most important thing.
1. **Peak shapes**: Gaussian, Exponentially modified Gaussians are very very common. Tailing is far more common than fronting. There is a very nice equation that covers all three shapes. Search BI-EMG in Google Scholar and you would find it. "BI" here is bi-directional."
2. **Sharp & wide peaks**: It is a relative term. You have to check what maximum efficiencies are achievable on instruments on GC, SFC and LC.
3. **Different levels of skewness**: Asymmetry of 2 is usually the maximum allowed number. Asymmetry of 1 is highly desirable. In practice it is possible to obtain 1.0 to 1.1.
4. **Baseline drifts**: Look more like linear ramps. You have to familiarize yourself with gradient elution.
5. **Peak resolution**: Start from peak resolution of > 0.5
6. **Tailing and fronting**: There is a very nice single equation that covers all three. See point no. 1.
7. **Smoothing**: I have written a couple of papers on smoothing. You can play with wavelets (most complex), Hamming filter, Savitsky Golay, simple central moving average, and Gaussian weighted moving average is the most common. I cannot disclose which instruments use which method. You can assume Gaussian noise rather than uniform. To the best of my knowledge wavelets or FFT filtering is not used in commercial GC, HPLC etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, [PeakFit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeakFit) development appears to be stagnant for over a decade and it is a proprietary software. Out of curiosity, are you aware of any comparable open-source tools for peak fitting in chromatography? I've heard [Fityk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fityk) is a pretty good general-purpose program, but I never used it extensively in the field. And thank you for the insightful answer!

Comment: You are right, PeakFit is stagnant but it is still very powerful. I personally like it because it has a plenty of peak functions in spectroscopy+chromatography, which are openly visible in the help section. So anyone who is developing a new software, should have something equivalent or better. I haven't used open software.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm using SG for now, but it seems to perform poorly on my artificial samples, I'll see if it's better w/ Gaussian noise (it performed better w/ real samples though). I thought moving average widens signals too much and thus wasn't a popular choice, but I'll try it and others too (couldn't defeat WT last year though - was too complicated for me). As for baselines - I've seen cases when it's not linear at all, maybe it was a problem with the column or leftovers in it, don't know.. Wasn't sure how common this is.

Comment: As for why I'm building the software: I see how chemists who I work with suffer and I can't bear it. I've been working in Pharma for more than 4 years and all software that I've seen is horrible. Since I wanted to be more involved w/ science and I liked Analytical Chemistry the most - that decided it. I mean _scientifically_ the software could be good, but the actual _software_ part (how convenient, fast, intuitive it is) - it's all very bad. I on the other hand am very good at software part, but I'm week at Math/DSP/chemistry (frankly when I started I didn't expect it to be so complicated).

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev, Do you work for a company or is it an academic project?

Comment: @M.Farooq I have a day job for a company, but this chromatographic software is a side project that I develop with yet another guy, you can check it out here: https://elsci.io/peaksel/. BTW, is this the paper that you reference for BI-EMG: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jssc.201801131?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev, Looks like a good effort. Hope you succeed. Regarding the paper, BI-EMG is written there as equation 14, BI-EMG can also be seen from PeakFit help function.